# Continuous Increase in H2 db size after dropping and loading same data repeatedly

Tags: database, h2

I have an H2 db named `temp.h2.db` which is accessed by two applications. The first one accesses it through embedded mode and the second one through server mode. Through the second application I load data into the database. But even when I drop the previous values and load the same data repeatedly, the db size increases. From about 200mb, it increased to about 2Gb. This happens even when I drop all tables and load a fresh set of data (which is almost of the same size as the previous set of data). Is this a bug?

I tried `LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=32`, but it didn't help.

Could this due to open transactions? How can we the determine which open transactions exist? I did a recover of the db twice and it gave me some statistics. How do I interpret these:

```
---- Statistics ----
-- page count: 954655, free: 776787
-- page data bytes: head 13860963, empty 26006602, rows 35134291 (66% full)
-- free 91%, 876991 page(s)
-- data leaf 3%, 36622 page(s)
-- data node 0%, 268 page(s)
-- btree leaf 3%, 36567 page(s)
-- btree node 0%, 570 page(s)
-- free list 0%, 52 page(s)
-- stream trunk 0%, 8 page(s)
-- stream data 0%, 3574 page(s)
```

and the next set is:

```
---- Statistics ----
-- page count: 235708, free: 164636
-- page data bytes: head 13268512, empty 24936708, rows 33759452 (66% full)
-- free 67%, 159364 page(s)
-- data leaf 14%, 35139 page(s)
-- data node 0%, 267 page(s)
-- btree leaf 14%, 35338 page(s)
-- btree node 0%, 568 page(s)
-- free list 0%, 15 page(s)
-- stream trunk 0%, 9 page(s)
-- stream data 2%, 5005 page(s)
```

Would doing `MAX_COMPACT_TIME` help in any way? Requesting your help here. Thanks.

Comment: Have you sorted the problem? More importantly, have you found the reason the file size always increases even after deleting rows?

Comment: Yes.. we sorted out the problem by converting the whole data into ddl and dml commands to an sql file and then executing this file. Through this we could get all the data back but with a reduced size.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/301.
This is a known behavior, intended to have faster writes at the cost of an increased disk usage.